# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity (unable to open DEX file)

Tags: java, android, crash, google-play, crash-reports

I recently published an android app in google play, everything looks great till now,
but there is an exception (see below) that I receive sometimes as a crash in the console, it occurs just for some users !!
and I can't reproduce it at all.

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.bendev.ronda.game.activity/com.bendev.ronda.game.activity.RondaOptionsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.bendev.ronda.game.activity.RondaOptionsActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.bendev.ronda.game.activity-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.bendev.ronda.game.activity-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.bendev.ronda.game.activity.RondaOptionsActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.bendev.ronda.game.activity-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.bendev.ronda.game.activity-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
... 11 more
Suppressed: java.io.IOException: unable to open DEX file
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:296)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:263)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:230)
at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:112)
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:58)
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:57)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:326)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:508)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4684)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
... 8 more
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I'm facing the exact same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the package name matches in your `build.gradle`, `AndroidManifest.xml` and in your `RondaOptionsActivity.java`.

Looks like it's supposed to be:

```
com.bendev.ronda.game.activity
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you right about the package, but I don't use gradle to build my project, I simply and manually export android applications via the Eclipse wizard. It worked on many devices, but I don't know why it occurs and just for few users,